# sql remove duplicate and count column with a where class

Tags: sql

i checked this in  stack overflow i may not not find this, i have a student table with attendance sheet that after 5 sessions they complete the class and they graduate from the class, every day we save their information with "on going" status but on 5th day we save all these members information with "Completed",  i want write a query to remove duplicates as it is saved 5 times and the count the number of student who did not "completed" yet and their status are "on going", if their status is  "completed" then i don't want to count them.

below is the query that is not working.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) FROM STUDENT_ATTEND WHERE STUDENT_STATUS != 'Completed'
```

but above query also count students that their status are "Completed" however and in the other 4th session they were "on going", that i don't want that these members to be counted because they are graduated.

[image: example]

in the above picture student with id 1 "Completed" the class and their status were "on going" in the past sessions too, as this member has status "Completed" then i dont want to count it , but the member with id 2 did not completed yet i want my query to count that member.

Comment: may i please have a comment that why i am getting down vote, so i prevent in that mistake in the future.

Comment: Please include some sample data along with expected result set. This will help clarify your requirements.

Comment: As @GiorgosBetsos said, your requirements are a bit vaguely defined, in most of the sql questions it is also good to have the table structure, to help you the best way we can

Comment: `!=` is deprecated. Use `<>` instead.

Comment: guys i added a picture with more description  please kindly check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you have the table with the students and every time they show up to a session, you `INSERT` another row to the table?

It is not right to insert multiple rows and then delete them if they reach a number and so on.

If this is the case your logic is wrong, why not try to have a column `attendance_number` in which you count the times he has attended the sessions and you increase +1, and another column `completed` true/false. Then, maybe with a trigger, or however you want to do this, when a student reaches 5 in `attendance_number` set `completed` to true.

It is an alternate answer to your question but maybe it will help you when developing other databases, keep an eye out for these things. Hope it helped!

Once more I strongly recommend taking a look over your database structure, maybe take into consideration what i said before, but an answer to your question can be:

`SELECT Student_ID,COUNT(STUDENT_STATUS) FROM STUDENT_ATTEND WHERE Student_ID NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT(Student_ID) FROM STUDENT_ATTEND WHERE STUDENT_STATUS = 'completed') GROUP BY Student_ID`

Well, if you use `COUNT` and another column in the select you have to use `GROUP BY`, but if you only want the number you can do it like this, but you will have no relevant information:

`SELECT COUNT(STUDENT_STATUS) FROM STUDENT_ATTEND WHERE Student_ID NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT(Student_ID) FROM STUDENT_ATTEND WHERE STUDENT_STATUS = 'completed')`

Comment: can you plz check my question once again plz, i added picture with more information

Comment: Thanks @Raul Cuth it works and solved 50% but currently it is showing as grouped by, how can i query to distinct and count, to show only the number of student not their information

Comment: Edited, if it solved your problem please accept the answer, it is a good practice.

Comment: how to count only the number instead of grouping

Comment: you mean the whole number, like all the cases of on going for those that are not completed together?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130476/discussion-between-raul-cuth-and-mellad-qarizada).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, COUNT(STUDENT_ID)
FROM STUDENT_ATTEND 
WHERE STUDENT_STATUS != 'Completed' 
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
```

Comment: can you plz check my question once again plz, i added picture with more information

Comment: Looking at it more closely I agree with @RaulCuth, your logic is flawed.